# swift collectionview in tableview load images horizontally in collectionview

Tags: image, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I need horizontal images in collectionview, which is inside every tableview cell. The problem I am facing is tableview gets loaded easily, but collectionview doesn't get loaded before tableview cells, because tableview loads very quickly, and hence the array for collectionview gets changed.

The code I am using for the whole view, is -

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,NSURLConnectionDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var tbl_data: UITableView!

    var mutableData: NSMutableData!
    var response: NSURLResponse!
    var connection: NSURLConnection!


    var thedata:NSArray!

    var ary_OF_collectionView:NSArray!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        connection_GetPeopleList()
        thedata = NSArray()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return thedata.count

    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        //println("INdex===\(indexPath.row)")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! dTableViewCell

        var c_snippet:String = ""

        if let checkC_snip:AnyObject = thedata.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("c_snippet")
        {
            c_snippet =  checkC_snip as! String
        }

        var getImageArray:NSArray =  (thedata.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("images") as? NSArray)!



        cell.lbl_like.text = c_snippet



        cell.co_v.tag = indexPath.row
        if(getImageArray.count > 0)
        {
            if(getImageArray.count == 1)
            {
                var getimagePath:String = getImageArray.objectAtIndex(0) as! String

                if(!getimagePath.isEmpty)
                {

                    ary_OF_collectionView = getImageArray

                }else
                {

                   ary_OF_collectionView = NSArray()

                }
            }else
            {
                 ary_OF_collectionView = getImageArray
            }
        }else
        {
               ary_OF_collectionView = NSArray()

        }




        cell.co_v.dataSource = self
        cell.co_v.delegate = self
        cell.co_v.reloadData()

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        return cell
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return ary_OF_collectionView.count
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        var getImageUrl:String! = ary_OF_collectionView.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String
        println(getImageUrl)

        // This is image loader From == https://github.com/natelyman/SwiftImageLoader
        ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(getImageUrl, completionHandler:{(image: UIImage?, url: String) in
            cell.img.image = image
        })

        //cell.img.image = UIImage(named: ) as UIImage!
        return cell

        }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        println("INinininin===\(indexPath.row)")

       // var cell:dTableViewCell = cell as! dTableViewCell

     //  [cell setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate:self index:indexPath.row];

    }

     func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        println(scrollView)
    // println("INinininin===\(scrollView.tag)")

    }


    func connection_GetPeopleList()
    {





            let urlPath: String = "http://carbonchase.com/v1.1/get_jives.php?user_id=3221128362&at=0&newsfeeds&count=10"

            println("get_People List == \(urlPath)")

            var escapedAddress = urlPath.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
            var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: escapedAddress!)!
            var request1: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            self.connection = NSURLConnection(request: request1, delegate: self, startImmediately: true);
            connection.start()

    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
        self.response = response
        self.mutableData = NSMutableData()
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!) {
        self.mutableData.appendData(data)
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!)
    {
        if let jsonResult: NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.mutableData, options: nil, error:nil) as? NSArray {
              thedata = jsonResult

            self.tbl_data.reloadData();
            self.tbl_data.delegate=self;
            self.tbl_data.dataSource=self;

        }

    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        println("\(error)")

    }


}// END
```

**EDITED**

CollectionView is not working

Comment: You did not specify what is not working. Indiscriminate code dump does not help either.

Comment: CollectionView is not working....Edited the question....@Mundi

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? not showing data? not right frame? not scrolling? you should also show your `dTableViewCell` class. Is collectionView properly initialized?

Comment: Actually The Problem is When load tableview cell index no is Zero then its load collection view tag is Zero , but its not wait for load Zero , After 1 second its load tableview cell index no is first Then zero index collection view is not load properly and Then collection view array is Change and its not able to load properly image 
Ex tableview Zero index images have 3 images array on this time have show 3 images in CollectionView but its show zero images , Please check images parameter from websevices